# Hibernate memory leak

Tags: java, hibernate

I call this code fragment repeatedly and the memory requirement keeps growing each time I call it.

How do I release memory with each call?

```js
        final Session session = Hibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            final ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.count("totalLinePrice"));
            projList.add(Projections.sum("totalLinePrice"));
            final Object[] sum = (Object[]) session
                    .createCriteria(OrderR.class)
                    .setProjection(projList)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("shopId", getShopR().getId()))
                    .add(Restrictions.gt("dtime", ord.monthBackTime))
                    .uniqueResult();
            ord.num = (int) sum[0];
            ord.revenueTotal = (long) sum[1];
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new Bug(e);
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on eclipse use 'Eclipse Memory Analyzer' can help provide details of java heap use. Hope so Hibernate.getSessionFactory() adhere to singleton pattern since internal state of a hibernate sessionFactory is immutable.

Let me know if it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Entitymanager instead. You can retrieve the underlying Hibernatesession with entitymanager.unwrap().